# Installing Pigeon Planner

Tags: python

I downloaded free opensource software [Pigeon Planner](http://www.pigeonplanner.com/download) for linux. To install, I pressed ctrl-alt-t and typed in : `sudo python setup.py install` and pressed <kbd>Enter</kbd>. I was asked for my password and after entering received the message :
`python : cant open file 'setup.py' [Errno2] no such file or directory.`
The file is located in a folder called `Downloads` on my desktop.
Wondering where I'm going wrong?

Comment: It seems that you are using command from some other folder. Before using command, please check in which folder you are currently in using `pwd` command.

Comment: It's probable that when you opened the terminal, your $PWD was equal to "~" (`/home/$USER/` or your user directory) so your command `sudo python setup.py` was the equivalent of `sudo python /home/$USER/setup.py` where the file doesn't exist by your own description - it's in `/home/$USER/Desktop/Downloads/setup.py` thus the no such file error is valid as I read your description.  Provide the full path, or `cd` (change directory) to the location where it is then use your existing command.

Answer (score 0):

It's probable that when you opened the terminal, your $PWD was equal to "~" (`/home/$USER/` or your user directory) so your command

`sudo python setup.py`

was the equivalent of

`sudo python /home/$USER/setup.py`

where the file doesn't exist by your own description at that location; it's in `/home/$USER/Desktop/Downloads/setup.py` thus the "*no such file error*" is valid as I read your description.

Provide the full path in your command, or `cd` (change directory) to the location where it is then use your existing command.

fyi:  $PWD is a variable which contains your present working directory; ie. `echo $PWD` will display it, as will `pwd`.  $USER is a variable which contains your username, so `echo $USER` will display it, as will `whoami`.

Comment: Thanks very much. I typed sudo python /home/gavin/Desktop/Downloads/setup.py but still get the same result. Must be still typing the wrong string (when I typed whoami it returned"gavin")

Comment: @GavinCrawford I assume that guiverc mistyped the path. They most probably meant `/home/$USER/Downloads/setup.py`.

Comment: Thanks Kulfy - unfortunately still no luck - am stumped!

Comment: @GavinCrawford Did you download the tarball? Have you extracted that? What is the output of `find /home/$USER/Downloads -name setup.py`?

Comment: I didn't verify your path; you're release is most likely different to my own, and I based what I wrote on what you'd entered, and what it looks like on my own system.. *I expected you'd verify the path was correct; I cannot see your system so it was hoped to be a guide more than copy/paste*.  I also suggested using `cd` (or change directory) to the directory where it is actually located in hopes by doing it you'd see for yourself what your end result should be..  I wrote it as answer only because I hoped with more space it'd be more readable/understandable contrasted with comment.

Answer (score 0):

Let's download it and install step-by-step in terminal:

```
# change to Downloads folder inside home-folder
cd ~/Downloads
# download the distribution
wget https://launchpad.net/pigeonplanner/3.6/3.6.2/+download/pigeonplanner-3.6.2.tar.gz
# unpack the distibution
tar -xf pigeonplanner-3.6.2.tar.gz
# change directory to unpacked one
cd pigeonplanner-3.6.2/
# install needed python 2 modules
sudo apt install python-setuptools python-gtk2

# finally install the application
sudo python setup.py install
```

and enjoy. The application should be available from applications menu or by `pigeonplanner` command.

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help. I'm going to try the above instructions. (Kulfythe output from your suggestion was : bash find/home/gavin/Downloads : no such file or directory) so I can see I'm not inputting correctly. will try the above...

Comment: Yess!! Norbert, Guiverc and Kulfy - you are stars! Up and running:)